# Docker build "no such file or directory" but work with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I try to register with gitlab a image:

```
docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/xxx/xxx compose/base
```

But I get:

> Step 4/7 : COPY ./requirements /requirements lstat requirements: no
>   such file or directory

However build with compose work:

```
docker-compose -f dev.yml build python


services:
  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/base/Dockerfile
```

The file structure:

-Project/requirements
-Project/compose/base

How I replicate what compose do?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in docker build context, i suggest you try this:

```
docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/xxx/xxx -f compose/base/Dockerfile .
```